# How is signature verified on OKTA JWT token?

Tags: spring-security, jwt, okta

If I get an access_token from OKTA and paste it into the [JWT](https://jwt.io/) website it says the signature is validated. If I create a JWT token myself and signed with `JWSAlgorithm.HS256` and paste it into the [JWT](https://jwt.io/) website it says the signature is NOT validated.

How does [JWT](https://jwt.io/) make the claim the signature is valid for the OKTA JWT token?

Comment: Quite so. Thanks.